# How to load CAP file to java card

Tags: c#, smartcard, javacard

I am new to java card,Can you help me how to parse Aplet CAP file into the APDU,
For installing this CAP file to the card suported GP2.2.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using [GPShell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/globalplatform/) which will do the work for you. You need to perform a number of GlobalPlatform commands :

- Install [for load]
- Load
- Install [for install and make selectable]

GPshell will do this for you, as well as the security (you need to authenticate with SCP02, in a script that will look like this :

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect -reader "<your reader's PC/SC name here>"
select -AID A0000001510000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 32 -enc_key 11111111111111111111111111111111 -mac_key 22222222222222222222222222222222 -kek_key 33333333333333333333333333333333 -scp 2 -scpimpl 21
install_for_load -pkgAID <your package AID here> -sdAID <your SSD here> -nvCodeLimit 0
load -file your.cap
install_for_install -AID <your Application AID> -pkgAID <your package AID> -instAID <your instance AID>
```

Angle bracket items above should of course be edited in the script above. If the SSD is not defined, you might as well use the ISD's AID (A0000001510000).

Answer (score 0):

You should use cap2cmd.jar
That .jar file convert cap file into the LOAD APDU command.

Regards,