# How to install .cap applet from android application?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card, javacard, jcop

How to install applet to SD card from *.cap* file by android application? I have ready *.cap* file and I want to install it dynamically in android application. Is it possible at all? All that I found by this time is this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30474760/4898850) that say that this is possible if the phone supports NFC.

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisites:

- NFC support and a contactless card
- OR some bluetooth or USB reader with the vendor SDK (requires development)

Two options:

- your application implements all the necessary GlobalPlatform bits and pieces (inspiration: https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) and connects to a card via standard NFC or the proprietary SDK-s of card reader vendors
- you can use https://developer.fidesmo.com to load applets to a Fidesmo enabled NFC device, like a Fidesmo YubiKey NEO from the readily available Android app

Comment: For a SD card form factor you are actually most probably bound to some vendor SDK and must do the development  yourself. But for what is asked in the *title*, both of these two options are valid.