# Java Card Communication

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I recently bought some Java Cards:

- GP 2.1.1
- JC 2.2.2
- JCOP

I have created some applets using the emulators.

Now I need to transfer these to the card.
I am using the open source "gpshell" and "jcManager" to load the applets.

The problem is that I cannot load my applet. 
When I select the default Card Manager applet I get a return "6A82" applet not found.
When I run a Select command I receive again "6A82" return.

How can I determine the Card Manager AID?
If the card is not pre-personalized how can I pre-personalize it?

When I run the JCOP INDENTIFY command I get "0" on offset 14 and again "6A82".
This means that the card is not fused.

Answer (score 1):

The standard card manager's AID is defined by GlobalPlatform as follows :

```
 A0000001510000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to try it. Could you please forward me the documentation you used? Also do you suggest me to use tools like "GPshell" or "jcManager" to load applets and communicate using GlobalPlatform or to use a Java GlobalPlatform API to write my own software ?

Comment: Check wwww.globalplatform.org they have all their card specifications there. GPShell should be good enough for performing authentication with the ISD and loading package. It can also help you do some authentication and SCP02 crypto to another SSD in case you need to load data to your cardlet. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651128/how-to-load-cap-file-to-java-card/19659400#19659400 on how to use GPShell for loading.

Comment: It still returns 6A82... maybe there is no card manager installed ?

Comment: You need to have documentation of your cards from the vendors. I would be surprised if you cannot find this online. Have you checked NXP's web site ?